# How can I limit the scope of some CSS to a specific route?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm working on a React js application, i already installed bootstrap and i know how to use it, but the thing is React is generating a Single Web Page Application, which means, and for instance if i want the index page's body background color blue, it stays blue when i make a new redirection.

Is there any way to control my css properties to be just for a specific route ?

Here is some code :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../style.css';

export default class Login extends Component {
render() {
    return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div id="form-container-login" className="col-lg-6">
                        Hello from the log in Component
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What about making each route a `container` component which can have their own styles?

Answer (score 1):

Add the class to the page, not the route.

```
 <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} title="Home" />
            <Route exact path="/one" component={ScreenOne} title="Support" />
            <Route exact path="/two" component={ScreenTwo} title="Finance" />
          </div>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

---

```
class HomePage extends Component {

render() {
    const { history, title } = this.props;
    return (
      <Glass
        title={title}
        history={history}
        body={
          <div className="BLUE_BG_CLASS">
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <div className="col-md-12">
                <div className="header_container">
                  <h2>Overview</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think css modules is the best solution for your purpose.

You can find an example in this [article](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822), as well as other different ways to use css in react.

Answer (score 0):

The body will be a global style for all pages since it shows up everywhere. If you want a specific page to have a different color background you will have to give the container the full height/width and change that for each respective page. You will also need separate style sheets for each page and/or different className's if you want to use one global stylesheet. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it a good practice though ? Cuz that's what i'm doing now..

Comment: It depends on how big you want the app to be. If the app is large and many pages have different background colors it's not a bad idea to split it up into different style sheets. In this case making a container component that wraps around the pages would be a good idea (container component could wrap other components <ContainerComponent styles={styles}> {page component render} </ContainerComponent> . Stylistically it would be ideal to have a general background color that can fit into all pages, that's another thought.